# SSIS Multi conditional If statement

Tags: if-statement, ssis, conditional-statements

I am a new user in SSIS. I am wondering how I can complete the following below.

I need an if statement that reads IF Column 1 = 1 then 1, elseif column 2 = 2 then 2 elseif column 3 = 3 then 3 else 0. Just need to consolidate 3 columns into 1 column in SSIS.

Current SSIS Formula is only giving me column 1 and Null. I want the new column to show 1, 2,3, 0 etc.

[Column 1] == "1" ? "1" : [column 2] == "2" ? "2" : [Column 3] == "3" ? "3" : "0"

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct for the supplied data and conditions

Given a minimal reproduction.

Source query

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
    VALUES
        ('1', '2', '3', '4', 'ROW_0')
    ,    ('X', '2', '3', '4', 'ROW_1')
    ,    ('X', 'X', '3', '4', 'ROW_2')
    ,    ('X', 'X', 'X', '4', 'ROW_3')
    ,    ('X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'ROW_4')
)D(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, ColNotes);
```

Derived column formula - same as your except I eliminate the space to avoid typing square brackets

```
Column1 == "1" ? "1" : Column2 == "2" ? "2" : Column3 == "3" ? "3" : "0"
```

[image]

The only way you'd have a NULL in the derived column was if you had a NULL in the inbound data.

Adding this row in to source query will result in a NULL as the generated value.

```
,    (NULL, 'X', 'X', 'X', 'ROW_5')
```

If you need to guard against this condition, then you need to lead off with the null check in your expression

```
(ISNULL(Column1) || ISNULL(Column2) || ISNULL(Column3)) ? "0" : Column1 == "1" ? "1" : Column2 == "2" ? "2" : Column3 == "3" ? "3" : "0"
```

Comment: For some reason my final column is showing the first result and nulls

Comment: If you simplify your problem to the conditions I show, do you get the same results?